# Python Extracting Camera Video Motion Keyframes (AI tools)

Tags: python, animation, camera, artificial-intelligence, keyframe

I've been searching for quite some time now, but the only example I've seen where camera motion keyframes (movements) can be extracted from a video is in blender. I'm looking for a script, library, colab notebook, or any recommendation to be able input a video (for example, getting the camera keyframe movements from a video of a drone flying around) and exporting it to any type of file. The main purpose of this is double-sided: I want to be able to take the camera keyframe movements from the drone video and input it into an AI Art Animation and I want to be able to learn and add this python tool or library into a colab notebook of AI tools I've been slowly building over the months. Any help from you masterful wizards will be appreciated. Thanks!

I'm a "hacker", "novice-intermediate" level python coder, meaning I can read code and understand most basic and some advanced type coding. I'm able to read code quite well and manipulate it to my preferences, but I just don't even know where to start when it comes to the request I'm asking, ergo my post to Stack.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response! However I mentioned that I don't even know where to begin with any type of code to do what I'm asking, so that's why I'm consulting StackOverflow.